# cant display the input value using jquery. I tried to get the value but there is nothing to show-up pls help me. thanks

Tags: jquery, input

**this is my code:**

```
var nameid = $("#idname").val();
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var loc = $("#loc").val();
```

**this is the inputs:**

```
<input type="text" name="fname"  id="fname" />
<input type="text" name="loc"  id="loc" />
```

**when i alert the two input value it will return empty.**

Comment: Did you wait for something to actually be inputted?

Comment: yes, i have data from the server and when i put the data in the input text, then when i alert or display the value of the two input the value is empty.

Comment: i got the answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="fname"  id="fname" />
<input type="text" name="loc"  id="loc" />
<button id="btn">
Show entered
</button>
```

Js:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(e){
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var loc = $("#loc").val();
    alert('fname='+fname);
  alert('loc='+loc);
});
```

Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghnj4x6s/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="fname"  id="fname" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="loc"  id="loc" value="2" />
$(function(){
var nameid = $("#idname").val();
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var loc = $("#loc").val();
alert(fname);
alert(loc);
})
```